# Slow SSD speeds when cloning disks?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, clone

I am making a disk-to-disk clone using CloneZilla where both source SSD and target SSD are connected to the computer using SATA-3.

Both drives are from the same Vendor and have the exact same size and read/write speeds (Samsung, 250 GB, 400+ MB/s).

CloneZilla is showing me that that the transfer rate is 2 GB/minute, which translates to 33 MB/s.

Why is the transfer speed so slow?

I also tried cloning the drives via USB 3.0 which doubled the speed, but still, why is it so slow?

Shouldn't the transfer rate be close to 400 MB/s at least?

Comment: What is your Motherboard?

Comment: It is a GA-X58-USB3

Comment: One last question how are you running clonezilla exactly? this could affect your speeds depending on where you run it.

Comment: To be exact: I am running it in a virtual machine. I have set up the SOURCE SSD to act as a physical drive inside VirtualBox. Like I said in my post: The exact same setup but with USB3.0 Source to SATA Target gives me twice the speed, but still 10th of the speed expected.

Comment: What kind of virtual machine? What solution are you using? Are they attached to a physical SATA-3 controller?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
libata.noacpi=1
```

to the kernel command line, as suggested on the ubuntuforums thread [Cloning SSDs using DD is very slow](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141804%20%22here%22.). 
In my case, the copy speed from an SSD attached via a USB SATA enclosure increased by a factor of about 20. Your mileage may vary.